# Hashset First() + Remove() performance

Tags: c#, .net, performance, optimization, hashset

I encountered a performance issue today involving hashset.remove and I'm still unclear on what the problem was.  The question I'm left with is, why is the `Approach2` method significantly faster than the `Approach1` method?  I'm assuming it's the calls to HashSet.Remove but the MSDN docs say HashSet.Remove is O(1).

```
public class HashSetTester
{
    int TestNum = 20000;

    public void Run()
    {
        var hashset2 = CreateTestHashSet();
        var watch2 = new Stopwatch();
        watch2.Start();
        Approach2(hashset2);
        watch2.Stop();

        var hashset1 = CreateTestHashSet();
        var watch1 = new Stopwatch();
        watch1.Start();
        Approach1(hashset1);
        watch1.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Approach1 is {0:0.0}x slower than Approach2", watch1.Elapsed.TotalSeconds / watch2.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
    }

    HashSet<object> CreateTestHashSet()
    {
        var result = new HashSet<object>();
        var rnd = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < TestNum; i++)
        {
            result.Add(rnd.Next());
        }
        return result;
    }

    void Approach1(HashSet<object> hashset)
    {
        while (hashset.Any())
        {
            var instance = hashset.First();
            hashset.Remove(instance);
            DoSomething(instance, hashset);
        }
    }

    void Approach2(HashSet<object> hashset)
    {
        var tempItems = new List<object>();
        while (hashset.Any())
        {
            tempItems.Clear();
            tempItems.AddRange(hashset);
            hashset.Clear();
            foreach (var instance in tempItems)
            {
                DoSomething(instance, hashset);
            }
        }
    }

    void DoSomething(object obj, HashSet<object> hashset)
    {
        // In some cases, hashset would be added to here
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        new HashSetTester().Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you realize both functions are toatlly different? On Approach1 you remove one by one each item, while on Approach2 you completely clear the hashset at once.

Comment: Indeed, in `Approach1` you call 20000 times that 'HashSet.Remove`, whereas in `Approach2` you replace that with a single operation to clear the whole set and a bulk copy of the set to a List. Doing something in 20000 steps instead of one step is likely to be slower, but is that really your question?

Comment: The time also includes the time to create the collection.  The way NET works that will skew the time.  Flip the order and you wont see the same difference

Comment: @Plutonix that collection is created anew in both tests.

Comment: I know...thats the point.  If you run the test just once, the first collection will take longer to create.  Quick test *just* creating the hashset: first: 16084 ticks; second: 8862 ticks.  Ignore those and run it again immediately and you'll get closer times.  The totally different remove methods will have a bigger impact but the results are being skewed.

Comment: You're right Plutonix, reversing the order brings the difference down quite a bit.  I moved the creation of the two hash sets to be outside the timer to avoid that issue.  @oerkelens Maybe it is just the fact that it is calling Remove 20000 times more, but the performance difference still seems huge to me.  After I moved the creation code out of the test, Approach1 is still 1000x slower.

Comment: @Plutonix Well, you can fix that with a dummy call to `CreateTestHashSet();` before running the two tests, I guess.

Comment: 20K `Remove()` + 20K `First()` calls. They might be O(1), but that doesn't mean zero cost. Also the way `HashSet` and `Dictionary` are implemented, removing the first element inside loop makes `First` O(n).

Comment: @SteveVermeulen why are you so surprised that 20000 operations take a lot longer than 2? You are looking up the item to remove 20000 times instead of clearing all of them at once.

Comment: @IvanStoev You're right, it was the call to First() that was causing the issue...  If I change it to this then the difference goes down from ~1000x slower to neglible: `object instance = null; hashset.RemoveWhere((obj) => { instance = obj; return true; }); DoSomething(instance, hashset);`

Comment: I am having a very similar problem.  `HashSet.First … obj.Remove` is **not** O(1), it appears to be increasing with the size of the set as either O(log N) or O(sqrt(N)).

Comment: Yeah this is surprising right?  Though maybe not to @oerkelens.   Something about the implementation of First() involves partially iterating over the set I guess

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do something for every entry of the hashset and then just remove the entries why not just use linq instead?

```
hashSet.ForEach(item => DoSomething(item, hashSet));
hashSet.Clear();
```

This will probably give you acceptable performance when dealing with big collections.

Comment: This doesn't work in this particular case because the DoSomething method can sometimes add to the hashset